# Socket.io not accessible via domain name

Tags: socket.io

I have a socket.io node js application running on server on port 3001. When I access that socket connection via browser http://ip-adress:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1502735738006-0 It works perfectly fine.
I have a VPS on vultr with Ubuntu 14.04 x64
And I have a domain jackpotrolldice.com pointing to that server.

When I try to access via browser like http://jackpotrolldice.com:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1502735738006-0 then it doesn't work and connection timed out error comes.

As I am new to nodeJS and socket.io. So please guide & help me!Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, does that domain resolve to the ip address you are using? `jackpotrolldice.com. 299 IN A 104.28.6.46
jackpotrolldice.com. 299 IN A 104.28.7.46`

Comment: this is my origin ip and socket io work fine,but not work when replace with domain name http://45.77.65.27:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1502828097067-18

Comment: I want to secure the website,but it does not work to replace ip with domain name for socket.io and chat don't work in https.

Comment: Hope you got it sorted.  Posting a [link my answer for a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075509/socket-io-failed-websocket-is-closed-before-the-connection-is-established), in case it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075509/socket-io-failed-websocket-is-closed-before-the-connection-is-established